# retrieving the last stored value in variable using shell scripting

Tags: mysql, shell

i am trying to retrieve only the last updated value of variable date2,but all the times it 
gives 0 in the output,i think it is because i am retrieving it out side the block but
i only want the last value store in variable date2,how can i fix this problem.Thanks for 
your help

here is my code

```
 count=0
 date1=0
 date2=0

 mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_ivr_db -rN --execute "SELECT FeeSubmissionDate FROM     
 meritlist_date wHERE Discipline='phd' AND AnnounceDate<=now() " | while read value

 do
      if [[ "$count" == 0 ]]
      then
        let "date2=$value"
        let "count++"
      else
        let "date1=$value"
        let "result=$date1-$date2"
        if [[ "$result" -gt 0 ]]
        then
              let "date2=$date1"
        fi
      fi

  done

echo"V,date2=$date2"
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK can easily solve this issue. Here's an example of a simple script which lists all files in the current directory and returns the number of those files that have substring "test" as part of the filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -1 |
awk 'BEGIN { count=0 } { if (index($0,"test") != 0) { count++ }} END { printf("Count=%s\n", count); }'
```

Now if you replace *ls -1* with your *mysql* command and get rid of the while loop by simply using AWK in an analogue way as shown above, you should have no problems counting the lines of interest.